# Проблема с вложенными струкутурами

Tags: golang, struct

Есть следующий код, который реализует простейший случай балансера нагрузки.

**main**

```
package main

func main() {
    server := HTTPServer{}
    server.RunServer("8082")
}
```

**httpServer**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/engine/standard"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type HTTPServer struct {
    srvTcp TCPServer
    srvWs TCPServer
}

func (c HTTPServer) RunServer(port string) {
    e := echo.New()
    go c.srvTcp.Listen("8081")
    go c.srvWs.Listen("8083")

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10000)
    //TODO: e.GET("/getSocket", func) должен возвражать ip:port предпочтительного сервера
    e.GET("/getSocket", func(q echo.Context) error {
        response := "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + c.srvTcp.getBestModule()
        return q.String(200, response)
    })

    //TODO: e.GET("/getWebSocket", func) аналогично для вебСокета
    e.GET("/getWebSocket", func(q echo.Context) error {
        //response := "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + c.srvWs.getBestModule()
        fmt.Println(c)
        response := c.srvWs.getBestModule()
        return q.String(200, response)
    })

    //TODO: e.GET("/getStats", func) получение статов всех серверов (socket/webSocket), для сбора статистики Колей
    e.GET("/getStats", func(q echo.Context) error {
        response := []string{"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n", "TCP:\r\n", c.srvTcp.getStatistics(), "\r\n________________\r\nWS:\r\n", c.srvWs.getStatistics()}
        return q.String(200, strings.Join(response, ""))
    })

    e.Run(standard.New(":" + port))
}
```

**TCPServer**

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

const (
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "3333"
    CONN_TYPE = "tcp"
)

type TCPServer struct {
    Port string
    Clients []Client
}

func (c TCPServer) Listen(port string) {
    // начинаем слушать порт
    c.Port = port
    fmt.Println("TCP-server listen on port ", port)
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+ port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // закрываем после окончания работы
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        // ждем подключение
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        // отдаем дескриптор клиенту
        newClient := Client{}
        //нужно ли присваивание не помню
        fmt.Println(len(c.Clients))
        c.Clients = append(c.Clients, newClient)
        fmt.Println(len(c.Clients))
        go newClient.ListenDescriptor(conn)
        //go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func (c TCPServer) getBestModule() string {
    fmt.Println("Get best module")
    //TODO: выбор модуля и передача его ip:port
    fmt.Println(len(c.Clients))
    fmt.Println(c)
    c.DeleteDeadClients()
    if c.Clients !=nil {
        bestClient := c.Clients[0]
        for _, client := range c.Clients {
            if client.ConnectionCount < bestClient.ConnectionCount {
                bestClient = client
            }
        }
        return bestClient.ModuleIP + ":" + bestClient.ModulePort
    }
    return ""
}

func (c TCPServer) getStatistics() string {
    fmt.Println("Get statistics")
    //TODO: вернуть статистику
    c.DeleteDeadClients()
    temp := []string{}
    temp = append(temp, "Modules count: ")
    temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(int64(len(c.Clients)), 10))
    temp = append(temp, "\r\n")
    var summConnections int64 = 0
    for _, client := range c.Clients {
        temp = append(temp, client.ModuleIP)
        temp = append(temp, ":")
        temp = append(temp, client.ModulePort)
        temp = append(temp, " - clients: ")
        temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(client.ConnectionCount, 10))
        temp = append(temp, "; kiosks: ")
        temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(client.KiosksCount, 10))
        temp = append(temp, "; terminals: ")
        temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(client.TerminalsCount, 10))
        temp = append(temp, "; undefined: ")
        temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(client.UndefinedCount, 10))
        temp = append(temp, "\r\n")
        summConnections += client.ConnectionCount
    }
    temp = append(temp, "\r\n summ of connectins: ")
    temp = append(temp, strconv.FormatInt(summConnections, 10))
    return strings.Join(temp, "")
}

func (c TCPServer) DeleteDeadClients() {
    fmt.Println("Deleting dead connections")
    //TODO: удалить клиентов которые отвалились или пмерли
    for index, client := range c.Clients {
        if client.Alive == false {
            c.Clients = append(c.Clients[:index], c.Clients[index+1:]...)
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientTCP**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

type Client struct {
    ID int
    Alive bool
    Connection net.Conn
    ModuleIP string
    ModulePort string
    ModuleName string
    ConnectionCount int64
    KiosksCount int64
    TerminalsCount int64
    UndefinedCount int64
}

func (c Client) ListenDescriptor(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Listening connection", conn)
    //TODO: слушаем соединение с клиентом
    c.Connection = conn
    c.Alive = true
    for {
        // Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        // Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
        len, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Client connection error")
            break
        }
        // Send a response back to person contacting us.
        c.deserializeData(buf[:len])
        //conn.Write([]byte("Message received.\n"))
        // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    }
    c.Alive = false
    fmt.Println("Close connection ", conn)
    conn.Close()
}

func (c Client) deserializeData (data []byte) {
    fmt.Println("Deserialize data from client")
    //TODO: разогбрать данные от клиента  и записть их куда следует
    //TODO: ниже идет какой-то треш, наверное стоит его переделать
    s := string(data)
    temp := strings.Split(s, "\n")
    fmt.Println(temp)
    c.ModuleIP = temp[0]
    c.ModulePort = temp[1]
    c.ModuleName = temp[2]
    c.ConnectionCount, _ = strconv.ParseInt(temp[3], 10 , 64)
    c.KiosksCount, _ = strconv.ParseInt(temp[4], 10 , 64)
    c.TerminalsCount, _ = strconv.ParseInt(temp[5], 10 , 64)
    c.UndefinedCount, _ = strconv.ParseInt(temp[6], 10 , 64)
}

func (c Client) GetConnection () net.Conn {
    return c.Connection
}
```

Проблема следующая. При попытке постучаться на /getWebSocket или /getSocket не возвращает ничего т.к. массив clients пустой. Создается такое ощущение что я обращаюсь не к тому объекту.

Comment: И да, к этому TCPServer уже подключен клиент и вполне таки шлет данные и они парсятся и выводятся в консоль

Comment: Вопрос больше не актуален. Пакета `github.com/labstack/echo/engine/standard` не существует, а `github.com/labstack/echo` использует устаревший `golang.org/x/net/context`. Рекомендую обратиться к автору пакета, или заменить его чем-либо другим.